# Insert multiple value from one column attributes to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have this assignation function where the admin can assign a police ID to a selected memberreportID. Firstly, the admin will select the case, select the location and choose the number of officers needed for this case. For example if the admin chose 2 officers, it would then display 2 dropdownlist all binded to list down the policeID available.

```
protected void ddllocation_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (var connAdd = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = MajorProject; Integrated Security= SSPI"))
        {
            connAdd.Open();

            var sql = "Select policeid from PoliceAccount where status ='available' and handle ='offcase' and postedto='" + ddllocation.SelectedValue + "'";
            using (var cmdAdd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connAdd))
            {
                DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
                cmdAdd.Fill(ds2);

                ddlpid1.Items.Clear();
                ddlpid1.DataSource = ds2;
                ddlpid1.DataTextField = "policeid";
                ddlpid1.DataValueField = "policeid";
                ddlpid1.DataBind();
                ddlpid1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Police ID", ""));
                ddlpid1.SelectedIndex = 0;

                ddlpid2.Items.Clear();
                ddlpid2.DataSource = ds2;
                ddlpid2.DataTextField = "policeid";
                ddlpid2.DataValueField = "policeid";
                ddlpid2.DataBind();
                ddlpid2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Police ID", ""));
                ddlpid2.SelectedIndex = 0;

        }
    }
```

The first SQL command is how i insert them into the assignto column of the selected memberreportID in my database. I'm inserting both policeID i have assigned into the same column, assignto.

```
protected void btnAssign_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        using (var connAdd = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = MajorProject; Integrated Security= SSPI"))
        {

            String assign = ddlpid1.SelectedValue + ", " + ddlpid2.SelectedValue + ";

            connAdd.Open();
            var sql = "Update MemberReport Set assignto ='" + assign + "' where memberreportID='" + lbmemberreportid.Text + "'";
            using (var cmdAdd = new SqlCommand(sql, connAdd))
            {
                cmdAdd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }

            sql = "Update PoliceAccount Set handle ='" + assign + "' where policeid ='" + ddlpid1.SelectedValue + "' OR '" + ddlpid2.SelectedValue + "'";
            using (var cmdAdd = new SqlCommand(sql, connAdd))
            {
                cmdAdd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            connAdd.Close();
        }


    }
```

However i'm also trying to input this policeID into a table called policeaccount by including the 2nd sql command. This policeaccount has a column called `handle` which is suppose to show the memberreportID he is handling at the moment. I'm trying to let each policeID's account to receive the selected memberreportID into their handle column by using the OR function. I'm pretty sure there's a OR function for sql syntax. But when i tried to insert i got this error instead

```
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ''.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be as below

```
  sql = "Update PoliceAccount Set handle ='" + assign + "' where policeid ='" + ddlpid1.SelectedValue + "' OR  policeid = '" + ddlpid2.SelectedValue + "'";
```

Syntax is

```
UPDATE tblName Set col1 ='value'
WHERE col2 ='value2' 
        OR col2 ='value3'
```